# error 404, javascript http request goes to /favicon.ico in django server

Tags: javascript, python, django, http, xmlhttprequest

in views.py:

```
def recommend(request):
    return HttpResponse('hello')
```

i have this simple HttpResponse that is at the route /recommend. When i go to this route with the browser, i can see it's working, but when i try to get this http response with javascript:

```
<script>

    ///request to /recommend route
    function recommend(){
        const req = new XMLHttpRequest()
        req.open('GET','/recommend')
        req.onload = () =>{
            console.log(req.response)
        }
    }

    window.onload = ()=>{
        recommend()
    }
</script>
```

I get the error 404 in the browser console, and django says me that:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/favicon.ico
Using the URLconf defined in V_store.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

recommend
The current path, favicon.ico, didn't match any of these.]
```

How can i get this response with javascript? Why the request is going to /favicon.ico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to send the request

```
<script>

    ///request to /recommend route
    function recommend(){
        const req = new XMLHttpRequest()
        req.open('GET','/recommend')
        req.onload = () =>{
            console.log(req.response)
        }
        req.send();
    }

    window.onload = ()=>{
        recommend()
    }
</script>
```